# Eclipse Formatter isn't indenting correctly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

We are using the `Java Conventions [built-in]` formatter for our `Eclipse` projects. The code looks as expected after formatting and indents correctly when viewing it in `Eclipse`.

What we've noticed is that if we open the file in `Notepad++` (Or other apps) the indentation is actually incorrect. E.g. The method body has the same indentation as the method.
Also if code is copied from `Eclipse` it isn't indented correctly.

**Example 1**

In `Eclipse`

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

In `Notepad++`

```
class Example {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
}
```

**Example 2**

In `Eclipse`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

In `Notepad++`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Is this behaviour expected?

**Screenshot of spaces/tabs**

[image]

**All Characters**

[image]

Comment: My guess: in eclipse you are using tabs i.o. spaces for indentation (not really the convention). And in Notepad++ the tab setting is set on 0 spaces, which should have been 4 for java. (Notepad++: View | Show Symbol | Show Whitespace and TAB.)

Comment: @JoopEggen I would have assumed that any decent IDE these days uses spaces as default these days... but that makes sense.

Comment: Tabs are being displayed as expected. This is in multiple apps that handle tabs and there just isn't a tab there. I'll add a screenshot to show you. 
Also no it shouldn't be sorry! Automatically added the tag.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes? I don't know how I can improve the question as it's a valid thing to ask about.

Comment: P.S. I did not succeed in Notepad++ to set tabs to 0 spaces. Try the normal Notepad, maybe Notepad++ does for .java an outdenting/trimming/RTL or whatever..

Comment: The downvotes are typical: not a coding problem, unlikely to concern others (local Notepad++ problem). It should not be taken as criticism. Also see that some of us do care about the problem.

Comment: @GhostCat meanwhile I got convinced the culprit is solely Notepad++, somehow set to trimming lines, how unlikely that sounds.

Comment: If I open it in IntelliJ,VisualSVN, or Notepad++ I get the problem but Notepad I don't. I'm not sure which character it's not seeing as `Notepad++ is recognising tabs as shown in the screenshot above. I'm wondering if it could be how line feeds are dealt with as it's the only other character used.

Comment: I've added another screenshot to illustrate this.

Comment: Now, thats weird. And you are sure you using the default, out of the box eclipse setup, and nobody modified it?

Comment: Are you getting different results? I'm pretty sure this is the latest Eclipse with RCP with just this formatting selected. I can try it out in a new Eclipse and see if I get the same results.

Comment: @deHaar Re _"This question is not directly related to a programming problem"_, the question is valid and on-topic, and there are thousands more SO questions on formatting issues in IDEs! This is explicitly addressed in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"if your question generally covers…a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"*. Questions should not be downvoted solely because they aren't *"directly related to a programming problem"*. Upvoted.

Comment: @deHaar The existing of the **eclipse-formatter** tag (used for this question) also demonstrates that the question is on-topic for SO.

Comment: @Michael The displayed tab width can be configured (in Eclipse: _Window > Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors_; by default a tab is displayed as width as 4 spaces). What are you setting in Eclipse and Notepad++ for this?

Comment: @skomisa OK, thanks for correction... Was just a question…

Comment: @deHaar No worries. It's just so frustrating to see a valid, well presented and useful question being downvoted, and  I assume that's due to a misconception of what constitutes a valid question on SO.

Comment: @skomisa I did not downvote it, but maybe my comment made people do, which was not my intention...

Comment: @howlger I've found the problem. The `Java Conventions [Build-in]` profile uses 8 spaces for tabs. I'm assuming `Notepad` uses 8 spaces but `Notepad++` (and most other IDEs) uses 4 spaces. I don't know why they would use 8 spaces instead of 4.

Comment: Could this be something worth raising as an issue with `Eclipse` or is this standard used in some places?

Comment: @Michal Nope, the original Java Code Conventions (which is rarely used these days) says 8 spaces. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Eclipse formatter profile, ***Eclipse [Built-in]***, displays **tabs** with a **width of 4 spaces**.

In contrast, the ***Java Conventions [Built-in]***, displays **tabs** with a **width of 8 spaces**.

This is given by the [***Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language***](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), [4 - Indentation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html) as follows (highlighting by me):

> Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact
>   construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. **Tabs**
>   must be set exactly every **8 spaces (not 4)**.

These days, the original Java Code Conventions with its mixed tab policy and a tab width of 8 spaces is rarely used. You may consider switching to the *Eclipse [Built-in]* formatter profile.

Answer (score 1):

The `Java Conventions [Built-in]` profile uses 8 spaces for tabs.

`Notepad` uses 8 spaces but `Notepad++` (and most other IDEs I've used E.g. `IntelliJ`) uses 4 spaces.

To fix this copy the profile and change the tab spacing to `4`.

Alternatively the `Tab Policy` could be changed to `Spaces Only`. I prefer this as I don't feel tabs should be used for spacing. This question is an example of why tabs shouldn't be used.